# How to check if list is empty using thymeleaf?

Tags: html, thymeleaf

```
<div th:if="${tblUserList != null}">
 --content--
</div>
```

The above thymeleaf code is not working, where tblUserList is a list. So I want to check whether the list is empty instead of checking its null. How to do that?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
<div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(tblUserList)}">
 --content--
</div>
```

Comment: No Problem, glad to help!

Comment: `<div th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(tblUserList)}">` is a bit more readable in my opinion.

Comment: @Watercolours, yep, you are right, but for non-english coders "IF" is more readable than "UNLESS", so "IF NOT" seems prettier. But it is very subjective.

Answer (score 57):

With **Thymeleaf 3.x.x** you can validate list more elegant:

```
<div th:if="${tblUserList!=null and !tblUserList.empty}"></div>
```

or

```
<div th:if="${tblUserList!=null and !tblUserList.isEmpty()}"></div>
```

Comment: what if `tblUserList` is null?

Comment: agree with @SubinChalil , I am not able to check empty if it is null, getting error, any solution

Comment: @HiteshKumar are you sure that it's not works? I updated solution with check on "not null". I worked with Thymeleaf a long time ago, really difficult to remember behavior.

Comment: Yes, I am developing an app using Thymleaf, If list is null it throw exception on list.isEmpty(), it works fine we do null check, Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Or simply:

```
<div th:if="${!myList.empty}">
```

Comment: did you mean `<div th:if="${!myList.empty}">` ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of negating you could use thymeleafs inverted if `unless`

```
<div th:unless="${myList.empty}">
```